# Can CloudFormation populate a resource or dependency after the stack is built?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito, sam

A simple example of a stack could be:

1) A cognito user pool. 2) lambda.

Is there a way for me to refference the cognito user pool id that is generated when its built so it can be used in my lambda function(code) or will this need to be fetched and entered manually into my repo/config

or can I specify a cognito user pool id before its built? which ive not seen any example of.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are few ways of doing this. Probably the easiest and most commonly recommended way is through [lambda environment variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-lambda-function-environment.html).

Below is some pseudo-code of such setup in CloudFormation:

**mytemplate.yaml**

```
MyUserCognitoPool:
    Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPool
    Properties: 
        <properties> 


MyLambdaFunction:
Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
Properties: 
  Environment: 
    Variables: 
        POOL_ID: !Ref MyUserCognitoPool
  Code: 
    Code:
        ZipFile:

            import os

            pool_id = os.environ['POOL_ID']

            def handler_name(event, context): 

                print(pool_id)

                return some_value
```

Answer (score 2):

CloudFormation has a concept of return values.
You can typically use `!Ref MyResource` or `!GetAtt MyResource.someAttribute` to get corresponding values.
AWS CF docs typically describe which value are returned. For instance see [AWS::Cognito::UserPool return values](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cognito-userpool.html#aws-resource-cognito-userpool-return-values).
In this case, `!Ref MyUserPoolResource` will give you the automatically generated ID of the user pool.